прикрепить кнопку к видео-кружку и переслать контакту без пометки "переслано от"
скрин-пруф
Использую telethon, и бот_апи
Таким кодом:
await self.client.send_file(
    event.chat_id,
    event.media,
    video_note=True,
    buttons=[[Button.url("Перейти по ссылке", url)]]
)

добавляю кнопку к видео-кружку. И все отлично работает.
Но стоит задача отправить этот кружок контакту по username, сделать это можно только через Telegram API, тк бот сам не может писать первым. Но возможность добавлять кнопку к video_note есть только у USER BOT API (https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendvideonote)
пробовал переслать в избранное из бота, но при пересылке уже из избранного, контакту, посредством Telegram API, все работает - но есть метка - что "переслано из бота", чего не хотелось бы видеть.
И не бился бы я над этой задачей - если бы сам не видел скрин, как человеку был отправлен видео-кружок с кнопкой перехода на урл, без всяких приписок, что "переслано от..."
Подскажите, как так возможно?

Написано что можно грузить видео, не пересылая его, так и делай, в чем проблема загрузить его себе, отправить и удалить?

так пробовал, но проблема в том, что кнопки не будет, создать ее можно только в боте, пересылать бот первым не может, при отправке посредством TG API, кнопка не создается.

Да вы загрузите видео в телеграм с бота, и тогда его id прикрепите к сообщению, и не будет никаких переслано от.

отправка по id возможна только посредством бота, Этот метод работает только для ботов. Если вы используете Telethon для обычного клиента Telegram (не бота), там нельзя отправить файл напрямую через file_id, так как у клиентов (в отличие от ботов) нет этой функции в API.     Или что подразумевалось под вашей фразой " его id прикрепите к сообщению"?
